# Long List of CiviDiscount Codes Needs Management

Tags: cividiscount

How do you manage a long list (100+) of CiviDiscount codes?

We hold an annual conference and make about 70 codes per conference - so the list adds up.

[Can I remove old discount codes without affecting contribution records?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20508/can-i-remove-old-discount-codes-without-affecting-contribution-records) seems to be possible, although deleting them seems to be not the best practice?

Ideas:

How difficult would it be to implement a quick filter at the top that toggles the view to show active and inactive (or both) codes?

Or, what about a quick filter for 'Event' the codes are attached to? (or something like that?)

Alternatively - could a Drupal view handle this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable the codes and then sort by what is still active. I also recommend coming up with a naming convention that makes it easier to sort.

You could also set up an automatic discount for certain memberships per certain events, which would cut down on the need for so many codes.

Comment: What version are you seeing a sort by active on?  I don't see it on my installation. Also, personally, I think relying on "naming strategy" is a workaround, but the tool itself could/should allow for filters/etc. like a Drupal view.....perhaps I can code this or sponsor some change.

Comment: Drupal, civicrm 5.3.1 and cividiscount 3.4. A filter isn't a bad idea. But disabling old codes is a good idea too.

Comment: I'm still on 3.2 cividiscount. There are a couple bugs on the github that would prevent me from updating right now

Comment: I use GIT also and I created a separate repository for my CiviCRM extensions, since they are in the files directory, which is normally ignored. It made my life much easier.